# Android Studio Google Map doesn't load

Tags: android, api, dictionary, gps

If I use it on the Phone I can see the Google letters from the Map but nothing else, If I extract the Code to an extra app inside a Linear Layout as the same Map Fragment it works great. but not inside the hole app. It's inside a Linear Layout as a Map Fragment and As I said it clearly loads the Map because it shows the Google letters, but somehow it can't load the rest of the map

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);

        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        //Check permission
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //if permission already granted
            //call method
            getCurrentLocation();
        }else {
            //When permission denied
            //Request permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},44);

   private void getCurrentLocation() {
        Task<Location> task = client.getLastLocation();

        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final Location location) {
                if (location != null){
                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                            LatLng LatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                            //create marker options
                            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(LatLng).title("Me");

                            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                            //zoom map
                            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng,10));
                            //Add marker on map
                            googleMap.addMarker(options);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 44){
            if (grantResults.length > 0&& grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                //When permission granted
                //Call method
                getCurrentLocation();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to register your application on Google cloud platform https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform?hl=es

Comment: As per the Stackoverflow policy always add solution, don't simply put links

Comment: Yes of course you mean I need to create an API Key I did that in the key works for all the other Applications I created. But this maps application won't load